# asp net core docker serilog configuration

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have a dot net core 3.1 app that is configured to run in docker containers.
While I have managed to update simple appsettings config using docker `-e` flag, I am still confused when it comes to a bit complex configuration, for example, serilog config.

appsettings file:

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Host=172.18.101.65;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=pgadmin;Database=identityserver;"
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcesssId", "WithThreadId" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "D:\\Logs\\IDSvr\\Log-.txt",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:G} {Message}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "shared": true
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Seq",
        "Args": {
          "serverUrl": "http://localhost:8081"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  .
  .
  .
  }
```

I could update the connection string using `-e ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection="..."` flag, I am not sure how could I update the `Serilog`'s `WriteTo` configuration section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`WriteTo` is a complex object `array`. Hence, you have to specify the index you want to override. Lets say you want to override:

```js
"Serilog": {
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "Console" // this value
    },
    ...
```

You can select the key by `-e Serilog__WriteTo__0__Name` due to index 0 in the array. Then just pass it a value you want, like `-e Serilog__WriteTo__0__Name=something`.

To read that exact value in .NET Core `Configuration`, use `Configuration["Serilog:WriteTo:0:Name"]` in the startup pipeline.

Comment: perfect! exactly what I needed.

Comment: Should've been a more elegant way.